# filter detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, imagemagick, gaussian

I have to determine, which filter was used on a random picture - is there a common way to detect the right one (gaussian, prewitt, sobel, average, ...) or would it be clever to code some sort of 'brute force'-detection ?

I tried to find it with Matlab, but I have no glue how to search more *efficiently*. At the moment it`s like finding a needle in a Haystack. I also thought of using some bash-script and imagemagick, but this would be to resource hungry.

I tought this wouldn't be a problem, but it's very time-consuming to guess a filter and try it like this

```
f = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 1);
res = imfilter(orginal, f);
corr2(res, pic);
```

Comment: If you have the filtered image and the original image then it's very simple to determine the filter coefficients, and from there you can classify the filter kernel.

Comment: yes, I have both, but how can I determine the coefficients? with matlab?

Comment: You can deconvolve by taking the FFT of both images, divide, then take inverse FFT of result. See e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5465-fast-deconvolution

Comment: Okay, this sounds great, but the filter kernel is a matrix but I receive 3 values (1.0094, 1.0046, 1.0140) (the coefficents?) - i expected 25 [5x5] or at least 9 [3x3]. How can I get the convolution kernel?

Comment: @PaulR: That's not terribly numerically stable if the image has spectral nulls.

Comment: ok, but how to determine the used filter? as example two pictures return (1.0094, 1.0046, 1.0140) as result of FFT of both images, divide, then take inverse FFT... what do the numbers indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let **f** be the original image, **g** be the filtered one, and **h** the filter applied to **f**, so that:

```
f * h = g
```

Passing that to the frequency domain:

```
F.H = G, so H = G/F
```

The problem is that inverting F is VERY sensitive to noise.

How to implement that in MATLAB:

```
close all;
f = imread('cameraman.tif');
[x,y] = size(f);
figure,imshow(f);
h = fspecial('motion', 20, 40); % abitrary filter just for testing the algorithm
F = fft2(f);
H = fft2(h,x,y);
G = F.*H;
g = ifft2(G); % the filtered image
figure, imshow(g/max(g(:)));
% Inverting the original image
epsilon = 10^(-10);
small_values = find(abs(F)<epsilon);
F(small_values) = epsilon;
F_i = ones(x,y)./F;
H_calculated = G.*F_i;

h_calculated = ifft2(H_calculated);

% remove really small values to try to infer the original size of h
r = sum(h_calculated,1)<epsilon;
c = sum(h_calculated,2)<epsilon;
h_real = h_calculated(~r,~c);

% Calculate error
% redo the filtering with the found filter
figure,g_comp = ifft2(fft2(f).*fft2(h_real,x,y));
imshow(g_comp/max(g_comp(:)));
rmse = sqrt(mean(mean((double(g_comp) - double(g)).^2,2),1))
```

**edit**: Just to explain the epsilon part:

It can be that some values in F are zero, or very close to zero. If we try to invert F with these small values, we would have problems with infinity. The easy way to solve that is to truncate every value in F that is smaller than an arbitrarily small limit, epsilon on the code.

Mathematically, what was done is this:

```
For all F < epsilon, F = epsilon
```

Comment: It's also very sensitive to spectral nulls.

Comment: Yep, I know, that's why I'm truncating it. To me the real problem with this approach is noise. But it's definitely better than nothing at all...